# why do I get the “Error Code 1005 Cant create Table” in MYSQL with no typos in FK

Tags: mysql

With the following scripts, when i try to create NetBankingTransaction table, it fails with the following message:

> Error Code: 1005. Can't create table 'wah_schema.netbankingtransaction' (errno: 150)

DB scripts:

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wah_schema`.`Transaction` (
  `idTransaction` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `idOrder` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `type` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idTransaction`, `idOrder`, `type`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wah_schema`.`NetBankingTransaction` (
  `idTransaction` INT NOT NULL ,
  `bankCode` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `type` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'NETBANKING' ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idTransaction`, `type`) ,
  INDEX `fk_NetBankingTransaction_Transaction1` (`idTransaction` ASC, `type` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_NetBankingTransaction_Transaction1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idTransaction` , `type` )
    REFERENCES `wah_schema`.`Transaction` (`idTransaction` , `type` )
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Can someone please help me understand why am I getting this error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one works for me:

```
/*drop table if exists `Transaction`;*/
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Transaction` 
(
    `idTransaction` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
    `idOrder` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
    `type` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,

    PRIMARY KEY (`idTransaction`, `idOrder`, `type`), 
    KEY idx_idTransaction_type (idTransaction, `type`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

/*drop table if exists NetBankingTransaction;*/
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `NetBankingTransaction` 
(
    `idTransaction` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
    `bankCode` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
    `type` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'NETBANKING' ,

    PRIMARY KEY (`idTransaction`, `type`),
    CONSTRAINT `fk_NetBankingTransaction_Transaction1`
        FOREIGN KEY (`idTransaction` , `type` )
            REFERENCES `Transaction` (`idTransaction` , `type` )
                ON DELETE CASCADE
                ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

idTransaction in NetBankingTransaction table has to be unsigned. And you need an index on (idTransaction, `type`) in the `Transaction` table. Your primary key does not cover the FK requires since it's over three columns.

P.S: You don't need this in NetBankingTransaction table

> INDEX `fk_NetBankingTransaction_Transaction1` (`idTransaction` ASC, `type` ASC)

Answer (score 0):

You need a `UNIQUE KEY` in `Transaction (idTransaction, type)` to properly add that Foreign Key constraint.

Comment: Doesn't the PK constraint on `Transaction` already enforce that ?

Comment: No, the PK is made of 3 columns: `(idTransaction, idOrder, type)`

Comment: The idea is: One Order has Many Transactions, hence many transactions for a given order with idTransaction and type will make the combo unique ?

Comment: As per your suggestion, I edited the Transaction table, but it still fails the creation of `NetBankingTransaction`: CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wah_schema`.`Transaction` (
  `idTransaction` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `idOrder` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `type` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idTransaction`, `type`, `idOrder`) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `idTransaction_UNIQUE` (`idTransaction` ASC, `type` ASC) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;

Comment: `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` will not alter the table. Either `DROP` and re-create it or use `ALTER TABLE ADD UNIQUE INDEX ...`.

Comment: I DROPped it and re created the table.

Answer (score 0):

idTransaction is a different type in each table. One is unsigned and the other is signed. Try making idTransaction unsigned in the second table.

Comment: Market it unsigned, still it fails.